# Visual Studio version info in Jenkins?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, jenkins

I would like to add a post-build step (batch execution) in the Jenkins automation framework for provisioning of the build result. I would like to use the version number of the assembly info in the filename of a target file.

There seems to be no environment variable available for this purpose. Of course it would be possible to write some custom application which reads the assembly info and programmatically generates a suitable batch file which is then executed, but this seems rather complicated to me.

Is there an easier way to achieve this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using plain batch files for your build script? If so, consider switching to a proper build language (at least partially) as, for example, MsBuild or NAnt: they provide a bunch of useful features you can leverage to achieve this kind of task.

Personally I really like MsBuild: it is really powerful and comes with the .NET Framework so it is almost on every Windows PC.

That said, in MsBuild the correct way to extract assembly info properties is the [GetAssemblyIdentity Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx).

Hope it helps